# Set Background image in CSS file using python flask framework render_template

Tags: python, html, css, flask, web-development-server

I need to set a background image for my html. I have a file system of
Static

- css
- img

This is what I use to link my css file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/index.css') }}">`

In my css file I defined the background-image

`.bgimg-1 {background-image: url("/static/img/background.jpg");}`

However in my flask application I am getting the error of

`127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2020 19:10:04] "[37mGET / HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -`

`127.0.0.1 - - [09/Aug/2020 19:10:04] "[33mGET /static/css/static/img/background.jpg HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -`

Im not sure where does the `/static/css/` is coming from

I defined the class in `<header class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-grayscale-min" id="home">`

Answer (score 0):

I feel, it's because your `index.css` file is inside `/static/css/` folder and from there it is referring to image `(/static/img/background.jpg)` , so making the complete image url to this - `/static/css/static/img/background.jpg`

Comment: how do you recommend fixing this problem